# Displaying images with spaces in path when using Electron (windows)

Tags: electron

I've got a rather straightforward problem.
Some of my users insist on using spaces in their directory/file names (and use windows).
This sadly breaks the images in my app as the directory isn't read correctly.
For example

```
C:\Users\path name\Downloads\image name.jpeg
```

will open fine on Linux (and mac) but fail on windows. URL encoding (encodeURI) doesn't seem to work and I've found nothing on Google (though this should be a simple problem).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be a bug with Angular sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle when trying to use the photos as background images. No obvious solution except moving to regular img tags